# Node.js HTTP GET “ECONNRESET” Error on read

Tags: javascript, java, node.js, spring, axios

I've read all the related issues on SO and GitHub about this error and none of them seem to address this situation.

When I run the following code:

```
response = await axios.get('http://localhost:8082/panda, {
  httpAgent: new http.Agent({ keepAlive: true, keepAliveMsecs: 10000 })
});
```

I get the following error:

```
{ Error: socket hang up
    at createHangUpError (_http_client.js:345:15)
    at Socket.socketOnEnd (_http_client.js:437:23)
    at emitNone (events.js:110:20)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:207:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1059:12)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9) code: 'ECONNRESET' }
{ Error: read ECONNRESET
    at _errnoException (util.js:1019:11)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:608:25)
  code: 'ECONNRESET',
  errno: 'ECONNRESET',
  syscall: 'read',
  etc...
```

There's no stack trace beyond the `onread` call so it's unclear how I can get any additional information beyond the `ECONNRESET` error code (-54) passed to the `onread` method in net.js

This issue happens with every request - it is not intermittent.

A few observations:

- **when making the same request from chrome or postman the request does NOT fail**
- attempting to reproduce a successful request from Chrome, by using the same headers, fails
- setting the accept header to use 'gzip', etc.. does not help - I have tried all the recommendations including some weird ones like setting the content length and adding a body to the request despite this being a GET request

  - the error always appears in net.js, but happens with both the request and axios libraries

Here's the interesting part - **I can only seem to reproduce this problem reliably when I am hosting the server locally**. I am able to reach the dev instance or run the server in vagrant, via a docker container, without issue.

I am running macOS Sierra 10.12.6 if that makes any difference. The server is written in Java and uses the Spring framework. Here is the `RestTemplate` configuration I'm using for HTTP calls:

```
@Bean
public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
    //request timeout
    int timeout = 5000;

    //Connection Pooling factory with timeouts to prevent disastrous request responses
    HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory cf = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory();
    cf.setReadTimeout(timeout);
    cf.setConnectTimeout(timeout);
    cf.setConnectionRequestTimeout(timeout);

    return new RestTemplate(cf);
}
```

I've tried messing around with these settings with no luck.

Any ideas?

Comment: 'Connection reset' errors can indicate that the server process hit a problem (e.g. it crashed).  Have you had a look in the logs of whatever server process it is you are trying to call?

Comment: I was testing this while debugging the process locally - no crashes and nothing in the logs... I tried adding an interceptor to log errors and also changing various logging levels in my application.properties file - it doesn't seem like the request is ever reaching the server

Comment: What version of node, etc... are you using?

Comment: @Corvusoft sorry thought I included that in for - I've been able to reproduce with the latest versions of node 7 and 8

Comment: Please run `socat -v TCP4-LISTEN:8081 TCP:127.0.0.1:8082` in one terminal, this will show you all the traffic and then use `http://localhost:8081/panda` in your NodeJS code, see if you find anything interesting

Comment: @TarunLalwani I'm getting the following:

2017/10/19 07:15:20.094587  length=138 from=0 to=137
GET /panda HTTP/1.1\r
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*\r
User-Agent: axios/0.16.2\r
Host: localhost:8081\r
Connection: keep-alive\r

Comment: FWIW, I've hit ECONNRESET when running unit tests when I launch a server as a separate process before launching tests. You haven't said that this is what you're doing but if you are try to wait a bit after launching your server before making requests

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @LevKuznetsov, but this is not the issue. The server can be running for hours and is successfully responding to requests from the browser, postman, etc.. only requests from node are failing

Comment: @Jordan Did you solve this problem? I got the same issue.

Comment: @hshan yes it ended up being a docker issue -  I need to expose a port for internal communication

Answer (score 2):

I have the same issue. The cause was in my proxy settings. I make proxy-port localhost:8080 to my localhost:3000. That's why all API requests from my NodeJS app to localhost:3000 returned "ECONNRESET" Error. When I delete proxy-port, the issue was resolved. Check your net settings. Maybe it's redirecting problem

Answer (score 1):

This was a known issue with NodeJS and has been resolved.  Please see [http.Agent: idle sockets throw unhandled ECONNRESET](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/3595) for details.

Also ensure you have enabled the correct security settings when [opening a port](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/283135/how-to-open-a-port-in-macos-sierra-10-12-4) on MacOS

Comment: I saw that issue, but if this was fixed over a year ago I would think it would be in the latest versions of node 7 and 8

Comment: this issue happens without the firewall being on

Comment: Out of curiosity, what happens when you run your application under root?

Comment: that makes no difference